# Getting data as null from snapshot.data in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I can't find the reason for getting this error cuz there is data stored on firestore and i've also handled possible exceptions. Th StreamBuilder QuerySnapshot Widget is throwing exception. How could i tackle this problem plzz help

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AdminScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('complaints');

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: users.snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Text("Loading");
        }
        
        return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(document.data()['Name']),
                subtitle: new Text(document.data()['Complaint']),
            );
        }).toList(),
        );
        },
    );}
}
```

Error:

```
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
by StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> Widget
```

Firestore SS:[image: firestore ss]

Comment: can u show your firestore ?

Answer (score 0):

`StreamBuilder` will emit `null` as the first event if no `initialData` is given. To mitigate, you should first check if the data is `null` using `snapshot.hasData` before trying to read it such as:

```
if(!snapshot.hasData) {
 return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
}
// from here on you can access the data after you have checked it's not null:
```

Comment: CircularProgressIndicator() right? but still its showing same error

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo. Did you place the code above `return ListView` ? If so, maybe your data is null from the database and you should do a null check as @JideGuru suggested.

Comment: ok its showing no Material Widget found now, on ListTile

Comment: Wrapped a card to ListTile and it worked!! Thanks guys